# Gain the control on background activity by a click on foreground activiity

Tags: android

I have two different activity in one application and I am calling one activity on the top of other activity. My second activity is a ListView and is transparent, so i can see my fist activity as the background of second activity.  Now I want to gain the control of background activity without killing the above or second activity. I want to bring my background activity as foreground by a click on the second activity.

Any help or clue is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and new Intent for BackGround activity and start the activity as you normally do 
if You want only one instance of that BackGround activity use following attributes in xml

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```